# ionic ion-button color attribute not working in android

Tags: android, css, angular, ionic-framework, sass

When i run my app in ios it works fine, but when i run it in android it does not. The buttons and other elements appling the color attribute seem not to work in android. I have tried removing the attribute and they appear, but i need them to follow this style. I have also tried using class, ngstyle etc etc and still does not work as expected.

Here is the html

```html
<div class="buttons">
    <ion-button expand="block" color="color1" type="submit">
      <ion-text><strong>SIGN IN</strong></ion-text>
    </ion-button>
</div>
```

Here is the scss

```
@import url('http://fonts.cdnfonts.com/css/century-gothic');
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Century Gothic', sans-serif;
}

:root {
/** primary **/
--ion-color-primary: #3880ff;
--ion-color-primary-rgb: 56, 128, 255;
--ion-color-primary-contrast: #ffffff;
--ion-color-primary-contrast-rgb: 255, 255, 255;
--ion-color-primary-shade: #3171e0;
--ion-color-primary-tint: #4c8dff;
/** secondary **/
--ion-color-secondary: #3dc2ff;
--ion-color-secondary-rgb: 61, 194, 255;
--ion-color-secondary-contrast: #ffffff;
--ion-color-secondary-contrast-rgb: 255, 255, 255;
--ion-color-secondary-shade: #36abe0;
--ion-color-secondary-tint: #50c8ff;
/** tertiary **/
--ion-color-tertiary: #5260ff;
--ion-color-tertiary-rgb: 82, 96, 255;
--ion-color-tertiary-contrast: #ffffff;
--ion-color-tertiary-contrast-rgb: 255, 255, 255;
--ion-color-tertiary-shade: #4854e0;
--ion-color-tertiary-tint: #6370ff;
/** success **/
--ion-color-success: #006039;
--ion-color-success-rgb: 45, 211, 111;
--ion-color-success-contrast: #ffffff;
--ion-color-success-contrast-rgb: 255, 255, 255;
--ion-color-success-shade: #006039;
--ion-color-success-tint: #006039;
/** warning **/
--ion-color-warning: #ffc409;
--ion-color-warning-rgb: 255, 196, 9;
--ion-color-warning-contrast: #000000;
--ion-color-warning-contrast-rgb: 0, 0, 0;
--ion-color-warning-shade: #e0ac08;
--ion-color-warning-tint: #ffca22;
/** danger **/
--ion-color-danger: #eb445a;
--ion-color-danger-rgb: 235, 68, 90;
--ion-color-danger-contrast: #ffffff;
--ion-color-danger-contrast-rgb: 255, 255, 255;
--ion-color-danger-shade: #cf3c4f;
--ion-color-danger-tint: #ed576b;
/** dark **/
--ion-color-dark: #222428;
--ion-color-dark-rgb: 34, 36, 40;
--ion-color-dark-contrast: #ffffff;
--ion-color-dark-contrast-rgb: 255, 255, 255;
--ion-color-dark-shade: #1e2023;
--ion-color-dark-tint: #383a3e;
/** medium **/
--ion-color-medium: #92949c;
--ion-color-medium-rgb: 146, 148, 156;
--ion-color-medium-contrast: #ffffff;
--ion-color-medium-contrast-rgb: 255, 255, 255;
--ion-color-medium-shade: #808289;
--ion-color-medium-tint: #9d9fa6;
/** light **/
--ion-color-light: #f4f5f8;
--ion-color-light-rgb: 244, 245, 248;
--ion-color-light-contrast: #000000;
--ion-color-light-contrast-rgb: 0, 0, 0;
--ion-color-light-shade: #d7d8da;
--ion-color-light-tint: #f5f6f9;
--ion-color-color1: #006039;
--ion-color-color2: #9e9c9c;
--ion-color-color3: black;
--ion-color-white: #ffffff;
.ion-color-color1 {
    --ion-color-base: #006039;
    --ion-color-base-rgb: #006039;
    --ion-color-contrast: #ffffff;
    --ion-color-contrast-rgb: 255, 255, 255;
    --ion-color-shade: #006039;
    --ion-color-tint: #006039;
}
.ion-color-color2 {
    --ion-color-base: #9e9c9c;
    --ion-color-base-rgb: rgb(158, 156, 156);
    --ion-color-contrast: #ffffff;
    --ion-color-contrast-rgb: 255, 255, 255;
    --ion-color-shade: #8b8a8a;
    --ion-color-tint: #c7c6c6;
}
.ion-color-color3 {
    --ion-color-base: black;
    --ion-color-base-rgb: rgb(158, 156, 156);
    --ion-color-contrast: #ffffff;
    --ion-color-contrast-rgb: 255, 255, 255;
    --ion-color-shade: black;
    --ion-color-tint: black;
}
.ion-color-white {
    --ion-color-base: #ffffff;
    --ion-color-base-rgb: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    --ion-color-contrast: #ffffff;
    --ion-color-contrast-rgb: 255, 255, 255;
    --ion-color-shade: #ffffff;
    --ion-color-tint: #ffffff;
}
}

@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {

body {
    --ion-color-primary: #428cff;
    --ion-color-primary-rgb: 66, 140, 255;
    --ion-color-primary-contrast: #ffffff;
    --ion-color-primary-contrast-rgb: 255, 255, 255;
    --ion-color-primary-shade: #3a7be0;
    --ion-color-primary-tint: #5598ff;
    --ion-color-secondary: #50c8ff;
    --ion-color-secondary-rgb: 80, 200, 255;
    --ion-color-secondary-contrast: #ffffff;
    --ion-color-secondary-contrast-rgb: 255, 255, 255;
    --ion-color-secondary-shade: #46b0e0;
    --ion-color-secondary-tint: #62ceff;
    --ion-color-tertiary: #6a64ff;
    --ion-color-tertiary-rgb: 106, 100, 255;
    --ion-color-tertiary-contrast: #ffffff;
    --ion-color-tertiary-contrast-rgb: 255, 255, 255;
    --ion-color-tertiary-shade: #5d58e0;
    --ion-color-tertiary-tint: #7974ff;
    --ion-color-success: #006039;
    --ion-color-success-rgb: 47, 223, 117;
    --ion-color-success-contrast: #000000;
    --ion-color-success-contrast-rgb: 0, 0, 0;
    --ion-color-success-shade: #006039;
    --ion-color-success-tint: #006039;
    --ion-color-warning: #ffd534;
    --ion-color-warning-rgb: 255, 213, 52;
    --ion-color-warning-contrast: #000000;
    --ion-color-warning-contrast-rgb: 0, 0, 0;
    --ion-color-warning-shade: #e0bb2e;
    --ion-color-warning-tint: #ffd948;
    --ion-color-danger: #ff4961;
    --ion-color-danger-rgb: 255, 73, 97;
    --ion-color-danger-contrast: #ffffff;
    --ion-color-danger-contrast-rgb: 255, 255, 255;
    --ion-color-danger-shade: #e04055;
    --ion-color-danger-tint: #ff5b71;
    --ion-color-dark: #f4f5f8;
    --ion-color-dark-rgb: 244, 245, 248;
    --ion-color-dark-contrast: #000000;
    --ion-color-dark-contrast-rgb: 0, 0, 0;
    --ion-color-dark-shade: #d7d8da;
    --ion-color-dark-tint: #f5f6f9;
    --ion-color-medium: #989aa2;
    --ion-color-medium-rgb: 152, 154, 162;
    --ion-color-medium-contrast: #000000;
    --ion-color-medium-contrast-rgb: 0, 0, 0;
    --ion-color-medium-shade: #86888f;
    --ion-color-medium-tint: #a2a4ab;
    --ion-color-light: #222428;
    --ion-color-light-rgb: 34, 36, 40;
    --ion-color-light-contrast: #ffffff;
    --ion-color-light-contrast-rgb: 255, 255, 255;
    --ion-color-light-shade: #1e2023;
    --ion-color-light-tint: #383a3e;
}

.ios body {
    --ion-background-color: #000000;
    --ion-background-color-rgb: 0, 0, 0;
    --ion-text-color: #ffffff;
    --ion-text-color-rgb: 255, 255, 255;
    --ion-color-step-50: #0d0d0d;
    --ion-color-step-100: #1a1a1a;
    --ion-color-step-150: #262626;
    --ion-color-step-200: #333333;
    --ion-color-step-250: #404040;
    --ion-color-step-300: #4d4d4d;
    --ion-color-step-350: #595959;
    --ion-color-step-400: #666666;
    --ion-color-step-450: #737373;
    --ion-color-step-500: #808080;
    --ion-color-step-550: #8c8c8c;
    --ion-color-step-600: #999999;
    --ion-color-step-650: #a6a6a6;
    --ion-color-step-700: #b3b3b3;
    --ion-color-step-750: #bfbfbf;
    --ion-color-step-800: #cccccc;
    --ion-color-step-850: #d9d9d9;
    --ion-color-step-900: #e6e6e6;
    --ion-color-step-950: #f2f2f2;
    --ion-toolbar-background: #0d0d0d;
    --ion-item-background: #000000;
}

.md body {
    --ion-background-color: #121212;
    --ion-background-color-rgb: 18, 18, 18;
    --ion-text-color: #ffffff;
    --ion-text-color-rgb: 255, 255, 255;
    --ion-border-color: #222222;
    --ion-color-step-50: #1e1e1e;
    --ion-color-step-100: #2a2a2a;
    --ion-color-step-150: #363636;
    --ion-color-step-200: #414141;
    --ion-color-step-250: #4d4d4d;
    --ion-color-step-300: #595959;
    --ion-color-step-350: #656565;
    --ion-color-step-400: #717171;
    --ion-color-step-450: #7d7d7d;
    --ion-color-step-500: #898989;
    --ion-color-step-550: #949494;
    --ion-color-step-600: #a0a0a0;
    --ion-color-step-650: #acacac;
    --ion-color-step-700: #b8b8b8;
    --ion-color-step-750: #c4c4c4;
    --ion-color-step-800: #d0d0d0;
    --ion-color-step-850: #dbdbdb;
    --ion-color-step-900: #e7e7e7;
    --ion-color-step-950: #f3f3f3;
    --ion-item-background: #1e1e1e;
    --ion-toolbar-background: #1f1f1f;
    --ion-tab-bar-background: #1f1f1f;
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

`Add this in variable.scss` file
Here i set black color.

```
:root {
      --ion-color-black: #000000;
      --ion-color-black-rgb: 0, 0, 0;
      --ion-color-black-contrast: #ffffff;
      --ion-color-black-contrast-rgb: 255, 255, 255;
      --ion-color-black-shade: #000000;
      --ion-color-black-tint: #1a1a1a;
    }
    
    .ion-color-black {
      --ion-color-base: var(--ion-color-black);
      --ion-color-base-rgb: var(--ion-color-black-rgb);
      --ion-color-contrast: var(--ion-color-black-contrast);
      --ion-color-contrast-rgb: var(--ion-color-black-contrast-rgb);
      --ion-color-shade: var(--ion-color-black-shade);
      --ion-color-tint: var(--ion-color-black-tint);
    }
```

`HTML File`

```
   <ion-button expand="block" color="black" type="submit">
          <ion-text><strong>SIGN IN</strong></ion-text>
    </ion-button>
```